# Make C and ASM files in the same makefile fails

Tags: c, linux, assembly, makefile, cross-compiling

I have written a Makefile to generate a kernel image from both ASM and C sources however it fails to compile the C sources. I think the error is in using two object lists one for ASM and one for C. If there are other issues with the file please feel free to tell me.

**Terminal Output**

```
arm-none-eabi-as -I source/ source/maths.s -o build/maths.o
arm-none-eabi-as -I source/ source/tags.s -o build/tags.o
make: *** No rule to make target 'build/firstCFile.o', needed by 'build/output.elf'.  Stop.
```

**Makefile**

```
# The toolchain to use. arm-none-eabi works, but there does exist 
# arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi.
ARMGNU ?= arm-none-eabi

# The intermediate directory for compiled object files.
BUILD = build/

# The directory in which source files are stored.
SOURCE = source/

# The name of the output file to generate.
TARGET = bin/kernel.img

# The name of the assembler listing file to generate.
LIST = bin/kernel.list

# The name of the map file to generate.
MAP = bin/kernel.map

# The name of the linker script to use.
LINKER = kernel.ld

# The names of libraries to use.
LIBRARIES := csud

# The names of all object files that must be generated. Deduced from the 
# assembly code files in source.
OBJECTS := $(patsubst $(SOURCE)%.s,$(BUILD)%.o,$(wildcard $(SOURCE)*.s))

OBJECTS2 := $(patsubst $(SOURCE)%.c,$(BUILD)%.o,$(wildcard $(SOURCE)*.c))

# Rule to make everything.
all: $(TARGET) $(LIST)

# Rule to remake everything. Does not include clean.
rebuild: all

# Rule to make the listing file.
$(LIST) : $(BUILD)output.elf
    $(ARMGNU)-objdump -d $(BUILD)output.elf > $(LIST)

# Rule to make the image file.
$(TARGET) : $(BUILD)output.elf
    $(ARMGNU)-objcopy $(BUILD)output.elf -O binary $(TARGET) 

# Rule to make the elf file.
$(BUILD)output.elf : $(OBJECTS) $(OBJECTS2) $(LINKER)
    $(ARMGNU)-ld --no-undefined $(OBJECTS) $(OBJECTS2) -L. $(patsubst %,-l %,$(LIBRARIES)) -Map $(MAP) -o $(BUILD)output.elf -T $(LINKER)

# Rule to make the object files.
$(BUILD)%.o: $(SOURCE)%.s
    $(ARMGNU)-as -I $(SOURCE) $< -o $@

$(BUILD):
    mkdir $@
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a rule to make from the c source:

```
$(BUILD)%.o : $(SOURCE)%.c 
    $(ARMGNU)-gcc -c -I $(SOURCE) $< -o $@
```